# Error saying "There was an error while getting the sharing information" after installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: gnome, usb, 22.04

I've recently(2 days ago) installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on x86-64 and today I am getting this error saying:

```
There was an error while getting the sharing information
Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
```

[image]

**My question is** is how can I solve this error. When this error occurs I am not able to use the file explorer anymore and everytime I've to restart the system. Then after restarting, after around 5 minutes the error keeps getting back.

Comment: have you tried "sudo apt-get install samba-common-bin" ?

Comment: @nb52er No not yet

Comment: try and tell us if it works :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. With the error dialogue focused, Alt+F4 will kill it and allow you to use the filesystem. In my case it was caused by a directory that for some reason had different permissions than the others (`drwxr-xr-x` rather than `drwxrwxr-x+`). In my case it was probably because I had used ACL extensions (the `+`) for permissions and this directory was missing these. If this is the same case for you, you can compare a working vs problematic directory with `getfacl <name>` in a terminal to see the differences, and `setfacl` with options to update them.